# SQL Server: Easiest way to copy users from dev -> prod

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

What is the easiest way to move (copy) users from dev database to prod database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the "Users" node in Object Explorer, Bring up "Object Explorer Details" from the View menu. Select all, Right Click, "Script User as..."

Review script and change any logins as required to refer to logins on the production server.